# How to get original text from EditText

Tags: android

I am new to Android, my question is how to retrieve the original value from the activitMain.xml of the android : text  (without saving it to a file)
I mean that in the original value was 
 android : text="aaa" 
then it was changed by the user to "bbb"
if i do textView.getText I get the current value (bbb) i want to retrieve aaa

Thanks

Comment: save the original value of the edittext before letting use to edit it.

Comment: you can store the value of TextView into list before changing and then get the value of list at position 0

Comment: i can save it also in a file - this is not my problem - i am asking if there is a way to get the defualt value from the mainActivity.xml  after the value was change in the screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(New answer with more knowledge of question)

Maybe you can do it with Strings.xml??

```
<string name="player_1">Rahav</string>
<string name="player_2">Martin</string>
```

EditText in your xml file: android:text="@string/player_1"

Then programatically you can set it to the first player.

```
yourEditText.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.player_1);
```

Comment: My Q is how to get the value with out saving it before...this field is can be changed and saved and then i need to retrieve the original value

Comment: Yes but you can save it in a string variable, it is not really saved. You can then do whatever you want with this string whenever you need to get the value of it. The original value will just be held in the string variable. 

I don't think there is an easier way to easily just capture whatever the original value was.

Comment: OK - i  will explain some mor about the field . lets say i have an app that holds the name of 4 playes -some day player 4 is not playing and player 5 is playing -so i am chaning the name of player4 to player5 (this value is saved so incase the app will crush the data will not be lost  )  the day after player 4 is coming so i want to press INIT button to retrieve the defaults name (with out saving it to a file ) just get the value which is currently in the activityMain.xml

Comment: Ah that makes more sense - So you want to be able to assign player 1 = "Rahav", player 2 = "Martin" and so on? And then if let's say Martin wont join, someone else is going to take that place temporary?? 

You can probably get this by doing shared preferences. 

Shared preferences are key value pairs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23024831/android-shared-preferences-example

This way you can do a call to editor.putString("player1","Rahav");

And then when you want to retrieve this again you can do:

prefs.getString("player1", null);

Hope this works helps you :)

Comment: thank you BUT again - i know how to save to sharedPreferences i am asking if i can get the defult value from the mainActivtiy.xml some how

Comment: Anytime! Glad i could help :)